# How to modify string of a field for all documents?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework

Currently a document looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "630f3c32c1a580642a9ff4a0"
  },
  "title": "This is a title",
  "slug": "this-is-a-title",
  "Post": "this is a post",
  "iframe": "<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RzVvThhjAKw" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>"
}
```

But I want it like this:

```
"_id": {
    "$oid": "630f3c32c1a580642a9ff4a0"
  },
  "title": "This is a title",
  "slug": "this-is-a-title",
  "Post": "this is a post",
  "iframe":"https://www.youtube.com/embed/RzVvThhjAKw"
}
```

How to remove all other characters other than URL in iframe field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use an update pipeline with `$split` and `$regexMatch` for this:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {$set: {
      iframe: {
        $first: {$filter: {
            input: {$split: ["$iframe", " "]},
            cond: {$regexMatch: {input: "$$this", regex: "src="}}
        }}
      }
    }
  },
  {$set: {iframe: {$last: {$split: ["$iframe", "="]}}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-1Bfwip0M0V)